# Ethernet connection problems in Xubuntu 14.04 (intermittent packet loss)

Tags: 14.04, networking, xubuntu, ethernet

UPDATE: I have discovered that eth0 did not reset to half-duplex *all of the time* but only some times. Also, it occasionally appeared to have trouble resolving DNS.

Then, I connected the system in question directly to another host and assigned static IPs. Surprisingly, I got 100% success over 1,000+ pings. My next step was to bypass local router and switch and to connect Xubuntu system directly to the internet. Again, between 20th to 30th ping, packets started dropping out.

So I decided to try and spoof my MAC address and - lo and behold - I was able to sustain continuous ping both to the ISP's default gateway and to other hosts on the internet. I do not know if that has solved the problem, but just wanted to post an update. Still testing at this point. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

ORIGINAL QUESTION: Up until a few days ago, my Xubuntu 14.04 worked just fine. Then I installed security updates and ethernet connection became problematic. It would initially connect just fine, but when doing a continuous ping to, let's say, google I got a staggering 20-70% packet loss. Likewise, browsing would either fail or took a long time to load any page. (Meanwhile, wifi connection still worked flawlessly.)

Google suggested this had to do with the NIC driver (r8169), so I downloaded and installed r8168 but the issue remained the same. Unable to find a viable solution, I restored a partition image prior to the update; apparently, it is now plagued with the same problem.

After further research, I ran `ethtool` and, sure enough, it showed that the NIC starts off in full-duplex mode, but defaults to half-duplex mode shortly after I start pinging. Forcing full-duplex and disabling auto-negotiation does not solve the issue. I had no success disabling IPv6, either.

Here's what I can say for sure - it is definitely NOT a hardware problem, because WIN7 gets a solid connection on the same NIC (the machine is dual-boot). Neither is it network related, because all other hosts on the same network get 100% connection as well. I even tried running a Xubuntu live CD but to no avail.

Can somebody please help me figure this out?

Comment: Please be extra careful with your choice of words.

Comment: @heemayl Sorry, I didn't realize askubuntu was so strict about language.

Comment: @heemayl: don't go overboard on language.  The system detects offensive language automatically and it gets passed up the food chain  "Pulling out whatever little hair I've got" is mild to say the least.  Drop by in the AU general chat room to get some  exposure to much coarser language... **;-)**

Comment: @linuxgringo: I *do* suspect a hardware problem (cable or connector).  Windows drivers are much more tolerant to lousy hardware then Linux ones, so that is no measure of hardware failure.  It can also be an auto-negotiation issue, so swap the cable with another machine and give some feed-back so we can solve the auto-negotiation issue (in the unlikely case that's the problem)

Comment: @Fabby: u got it :)

Comment: @Fabby: thanks for the feedback. I ruled out hardware problem after testing a direct link with another Linux host, where not a single ping has failed (out of 1000+). I'm not sure about auto-negotiation, because even forcing it to full duplex @ 100Mb/s didn't do any good. Either way, spoofing the MAC address immediately solved the problem even though all other settings were at default. I have no idea what's up with that... haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BLUF: If all else fails, try spoofing your MAC address and see what happens... :)**

I've double checked everything since posting the update (see above), and couldn't find anything out of the ordinary. Meanwhile - knock on wood - ethernet works well with a fake MAC address. Hope this helps if someone else is having the same problem.